# using jquery.html() to save html elements to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a prooblem,which I searched a lot but couldnt find any solution,so decided to post a question.I have a webpage,which is been generated dynamically.It is required that i save whole appended body of the webpage to the database.I am using php and mysql.For saving the data I am using this:

```
$(function(){htmldata=$('body').html();});
```

With this I am able to store whole form along with script.
But the problem arises,that when I start calling the value from database,html data is coming out fine,but script is all messed up.

**when calling from database I am using**.

```
$html = trim(addslashes(htmlspecialchars(
                        html_entity_decode($_POST['htmldata'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
                        ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'
                    )));
```

What could be possible solution for this problem.I guess this will only work for data without script.Please help.

This is what my script looks like after calling from database

```
function test()
    {
        var formData = form2object(&#039;testForm&#039;, &#039;.&#039;, true,

                function(node)
                {
                    if (node.id && node.id.match(/callbackTest/))
                    {
                        return { name: node.id, value: node.innerHTML };
                    }
                });
```

Things like ' getting added

**My original script**

```
function test()
    {
        var formData = form2object('testForm', '.', true,

                function(node)
                {
                    if (node.id && node.id.match(/callbackTest/))
                    {
                        return { name: node.id, value: node.innerHTML };
                    }
                });
```

Comment: This is similar problem I am facing,still got no valid solution to it.

Comment: are you encoding `<script>` tags?

Comment: Whatever else is happening `addslashes` doesn't belong there at all...

Comment: Show your messed up script , just to know how it looks like, alse if possible do this with some small html and show your data and how it comes back

Comment: I have updated my post please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following,

```
//Function to remove slashes
    function striptext($Str)
        {   
            //Condition for not empty
            if($Str != "") 
            {
                //Condition to check whether the string is not numeric
                if(!is_numeric($Str))
                   return stripslashes(trim($Str));
                else
                    return trim($Str);
            }
            else
                return $Str;
        }

        //Function to add slashes
        function wraptext($Str)
        {
            //Condition for not empty
            if(!empty($Str))
            {
                //Condition to check whether the string is not numeric
                if(!is_numeric($Str))
                {
                    //To check whether the function exists or not
                    if(function_exists('mysql_real_escape_string'))
                        return mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($Str)), ENT_QUOTES));
                    else
                        return addslashes(htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($Str)), ENT_QUOTES));
                }
                else
                    return trim($Str);
            }
            else
                return $Str;
        }

So while getting post values you can use,

$html = wraptext($_POST['htmldata']);

And while fetching and displaying from database you can use,

echo striptext($your_variable);

And for displaying datas with script tags you can use,

echo striptext(html_entity_decode($your_variable, ENT_QUOTES));
```